# Code boxes are one line

Tags: bug, status-norepro, firefox, markdown-preview

All the code boxes are appearing as 1 line to me. This:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Appears thus:

```
#include <stdio.h>  int main() {     printf("Hello, world!\n");     return 0; }
```

...which is making the longer code posts harder to read. Someone posted a binary search tree, which was just impossible to read like that.

It appears correct in the preview as I write this.

Firefox 3.6.3, Gentoo Linux 2.6.32

*Edit*: To clarify: The correct version (with newlines) appears briefly on both Stack Overflow and Meta, but as soon as syntax highlighting is applied (which is almost instantly), then it collapses to 1 line.

This applies to the editor in the "edit question" part, but it seems to be a bit lazier about applying syntax highlighting. (It seems to do it when the box you type in loses focus, so as I'm typing this, it appears correctly, with no syntax highlighting, and when I un-focus the text area, a few moments later, it syntax highlights and collapses to 1 line.)

Comment: Both of the above code segments appear identical to me. (The first I typed with indentation, the latter with none, to mimic the bug I'm seeing.)

Comment: There was a question about this a couple days ago, I think. Let me see if I can find it.

Comment: Arghh.. I can't find it. But I know I replied to it in a comment.

Comment: Too bad "user:me" doesn't search comment text. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it back to normal. I have no idea why this affects it, but I was using an MSIE 7 User-Agent string. (And this, for some reason, wasn't reset when I started Firefox with -safe-mode...)

A reset of the User-Agent string back to the Firefox default, and a refresh, and it's working properly again.

The exact User-Agent I was using was: `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)`

Only the MSIE User-Agent causes this: The Netscape and the Opera User-Agent strings work fine.

Comment: oh, I see, you must have been triggering some IE specific code path in Google Prettify -- basically, as I suspected, an oddball configuration

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue (in Chrome) which turned out to be an incompatibility with a specific extension ([ChromeReload](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromereload/njoipeaphfnaplplihpbgndfojhdhmjo?hl=en)).

I would suggest if your user agent isn't the issue it's worth disabling all extensions to see if it resolves the problem. If it does then you can re-enable one by one to find the culprit.

Comment: Please name the extension, it's not a shame and would help others.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Added :)

Answer (score 0):

We can't reproduce this.

Have you tried in Firefox Safe mode (or another web browser)? I suspect rogue add-in.

Comment: Restarted in safe mode (webdev toolbar, session manager, and firebug are gone). No change - all code is still one-liner. Here & on SO.