# what's wrong with code formatting

Tags: bug, status-norepro, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code boxes are one line](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52864/code-boxes-are-one-line)

When I look at these questions the code is all formatted in one line, but I'm sure the authors didn't mean it that way.  Are they all doing it wrong?  Or is there a different way of fomatting multi line code blocks.

Seems to me like a bug in stackoverflow.com

[log-back and thirdparty writing to stdout. How to stop them getting interleaved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974857/log-back-and-thirdparty-writing-to-stdout-how-to-stop-them-getting-interleaved)
[Parametrize the WHERE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014786/parametrize-the-where-clause)
[SQL: How to use a column that was just added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015075/sql-how-to-use-a-column-that-was-just-added)
[GIT clone to external drive for backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887364/git-clone-to-external-drive-for-backup)

Comment: I'm seeing multiple lines of code in those questions. What browser are you using? (I'm using Firefox.)

Comment: Everything looks fine for me. Chrome 5.0.375.55

Comment: I'll toss in the IE8 no-repro vote.

Comment: Is it the same problem as this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52864/code-boxes-are-one-line Please post your browser and OS version.

Comment: Thanks Jon Seigel, yes it was a duplicate.  I had overriden my useragent in Firefox 3.6 and resetting it to the default fixed it. Would be better if capability sniffing were done instead of switching on user agent, but beggars can't be choosers.

Answer (score -1):

Resetting my browser user agent in firefox's about:config fixed it for me.