# Question code tags not working

Tags: bug

I tried to improve [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397621/how-to-count-the-records-per-half-hour-from-a-period-datetimefrom-and-datetimet) thinking the poster had messed up his code tags, in fact he hasn't as far as I can see, they just don't work?

Editing the post suddenly fixes the problem without changing any text (though you can't save with 0 edits).

[image: Chrome]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you are seeing? The code blocks look fine to me.

Comment: Added screenshot, now you've got me paranoid it's me!

Comment: So when you look at the question now it looks like your screen shot, but when you try to edit, it looks correct?

Comment: If my [earlier comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201843/question-code-tags-not-working#comment640965_201843) is correct, then the issue would appear to be a local issue as the code formatting looks good to me as well.  Maybe an unsupported browser?  What are you using?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Using Chrome 30.0.1159.69, one small version behind latest

Comment: @bendataclear I'm using the same version of Chrome (on Win 7) and it looks fine to me.  Do you have any add-ons or userscripts running?  It may also be caching?  Have you tried to clear your local cache and reload the page?

Comment: I'm almost sure it's some plugin/userscript you installed messing with the markdown JavaScript.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Disabled all extensions and it's back to normal, re-enabling them one by one it seems to be the extension `ChromeReload` causing the problem, strangely not on any other questions with code tags or in the preview...

Comment: @bendataclear nice, you better add this information [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52864/152859) (as a new answer) for others having this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved the issue thanks to psubsee2003 & Sha Wiz Dow Ard.

Found a strange bug in the extension `ChromeReload` which injects some javascript into pages, disabling this solves the problem.